# I am doing attribute binding in vue js image but it is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

In my vuejs cli application I want to show the images in order of @mouseover and I want to link them with id and show them but it is not detecting the imag

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cart: 0,
            imagestitle: "cat",
            images: "./socks_green.jpg",
            variants: [
                { id: 1, color: "green", image: "../assets/images/socks_green.jpg" },
                { id: 2, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
                { id: 3, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
                { id: 4, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
                { id: 5, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
                { id: 6, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
            ],
        };
    },  methods: {
        updateImage(variantImage) {
            this.image = variantImage;
        },
    },
```

examples like this

```
<div class="images"></div>
    <img :src="images" :alt="imagestitle" />
    <div>add<div
        v-for="variant in variants"
        :key="variant.id"
        :mouseover="updateImage(variant.image)"
    >
        {{ variant.color }}
    </div>
    <div>{{ cart }}</div>
    <button :click="adTo">addd</button>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Plf.png)

Comment: the extensions of the files are correct, I checked many times, it works when I export normally, but not when I bind

Comment: why dose variants have `../assets/images` and `images` doesn't? please provide the actual code your using

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it was just for illustration. I added my code by editing

Comment: whats updateImage? also its `@mouseover` not `:mouseover`

Comment: getting there, you set `this.image = variantImage;` but use `:src="images"` so it needs to be `this.images = variantImage;`

Comment: thx @LawrenceCherone I understand but the photo is not coming, `src="http:localhost:8080/socks_green.jpg"` it shows up in devtool

Comment: other than missing // after the http: only you know if the path to the image is correct

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the name of the image with slash in List like :
{ id: 1, color: "green", image: "/socks_green" }.

In template:
 `<img :src="`../assets/images${images}.jpg`" :alt="imagestitle" />`

or you can try moving all the images in static folder and use them like :

`<img :src="`${images}.jpg`" :alt="imagestitle" />`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below code which should work for you. No need of **methods** for changing the image on `mouseover` effect.

1. Take a variable `imageIndex` in `data()`
2. Next, on mouseover, assign the `index` of your `v-for` to the `imageIndex` variable
3. In the `img` tag, place a condition in `:src` which works as if the `imageIndex` is `null` then it will use the value of `images` and if not then it will use the image from the `variants` array by using the `variants[imageIndex].image`.
4. On mouseleave, the `imageIndex` will again set to `null`. (this is an additional code I have added, you can remove that line if you don't need to change the image back to default on mouseleave)

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="images"></div>
  <img :src="imageIndex !== null ? variants[imageIndex].image : images" :alt="imagestitle" />
    <div
      v-for="(variant, index) in variants"
      :key="variant.id"
      @mouseover="imageIndex = index"
      @mouseleave="imageIndex = null"
    >
       {{ variant.color }}
    </div>

    <div>{{ cart }}</div>

    <button @click="adTo">addd</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
data() {
  return {
      imageIndex: null,
      cart: 0,
      imagestitle: "cat",
      images: "./socks_green.jpg",
      variants: [
         { id: 1, color: "green", image: "../assets/images/socks_green.jpg" },
         { id: 2, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
         { id: 3, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
         { id: 4, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
         { id: 5, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
         { id: 6, color: "blue", image: "../assets/images/socks_blue.jpg" },
      ],
   };
},
```